# How to set the contents of meta tags dynamically in Struts2?

Tags: struts2, meta-tags, meta

I am developing a dynamic web application in Struts2. I want to load the contents of meta tags in head section of the page dynamically from the database. How this can be done?

e.g.

```
<meta name="description" content="Some value from DB" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Some value from DB" />
```

Comment: Why do you need some values form DB? Use message resources properties that you can retrieve from the action or JSP directly using a key.

Comment: Same way as you'd render anything else in a JSP (or whatever template engine you're using).

Comment: Thanks guys!!! It worked. I was using wrong tag.